# PostgreSQL Regular expression remove Space

Tags: regex, postgresql

Can some one please help me with this:

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('17 TH AV','^[0-9]+\s+TH ','\1 '))
```

is giving me `AV`.The output should be `17TH AV`.

I also tried

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('17 TH AV','^[0-9]+\s+TH ',''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('17 TH AV','^([0-9]+)\s+','\1'))
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nD5jY4/7

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told the replace function what the `\1` should refer to.

```
Select trim(regexp_replace('17 TH AV','^([0-9]+)\s+TH ','\1TH '))
```

This way you tell it with the parentheses to grab the numbers that are followed by space and TH and remove the space.